# In-game reward for facebook LIKE

Tags: android, facebook, google-play

I integrated a facebook `like` button to my Android game. Can I offer in-game reward (e.g. gold coins) to the player if he presses the `like` button?

I checked the Google Play Terms and such stuff, but we all know they are too general, and I don't know where else I can ask this. I know there are many Android developers here on stackoverflow.

I know that incentivizing the player for Google Play rating is prohibited, and it's the same with ad networks. But telling the user to `like` my own game page on Facebook in exchange for free gold in the game is allowed, isn't it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about it is about Google Play Terms and Conditions

Comment: @ianhanniballake: I understand. Can I ask where else can I ask such questions where I can get similar quality answers as on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Google Play has anything against this, but if I recall correctly, Facebook itself is pretty strict about incentivizing Likes and Shares using rewards (in-game or otherwise). It won't get your app removed from the Play Store, but it might get your Facebook API access revoked instead.

I've seen so many people doing it that I seriously doubt you'll get in any sort of trouble over it, but keep it in mind.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. I found this: "Only incentivize a person to log into your app, **like your app’s Page**, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions." Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy
 It seems that like is allowed after all?

Comment: Ah, it looks like you were more successful in googling for that page than I was. I think you should be fine, then.