# Android Java - Implement a Facebook like button

Tags: facebook-like

Good morning!
By search on web I read that Facebook Like Button is now deprecated.
There is an alternative?
I would like to make a button that when user clicks on it, the app's Facebook page will be liked and the user rewarded with the app's coins.
Is it possible?
Thank you and sorry for my terrible English.

Comment: what is the source of your information?

Comment: @luschn This page https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/, also android studio marks LikeView and LikeButton as deprecated

Comment: ok, i guess they really just remove it. your use case would not be allowed anyway though. you are not allowed to reward users in any way for liking your page. you need to read the platform policy before creating any app.

Comment: @luschn I read this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921381/in-game-reward-for-facebook-like and in the comments I read that reward users for like is ok. So facebook didn't replace likebutton? Sad story :(

Comment: the comment is very old, it was allowed several years ago but the platform policy changed. that is the ONLY important source, not some comment from 2014 ;) - since a few years, it is definitely not allowed. facebook made is nearly impossible to check for successful likes anyway.

Comment: hahaha sure, you're right. So I will say no to this idea. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incentivizing/Rewarding users is not allowed anymore. A few years ago, Facebook changed their policy about that:

> 4.4. Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, check-in at a place, or to use Messenger to
>   communicate with your business. Don’t incentivize other actions.
>
> Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Withouth the `user_likes` permission, it is not possible to detect if a user liked some Page anymore anyway. And you would not get that permission approved in the neccessary review process for a use case that is not allowed, of course.